# "away for a weeks" or "away till 1 week"

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis, time

I want to tell someone that

Situation:

"I need to give a reasonable reason to schedule meeting trip in this week because my family is not with me for this week."

then which is a correct and right sentence

> My family is away from me for 1 week.

or

> I am away from my family for 1 week.

or

> My family is away till 1 week.

or

> My family is away for a week.

Comment: IMHO it is best you research, cite and present the sentence you think is best ... then ask for specific advice.  Otherwise this will be considered 'proofreading'.

Comment: I have formed 3 sentence and mentioned in the answer. I m confused which is correct.

Comment: Are you at home, and your family has gone away on holiday for a week? Or have you traveled for business, and your family is travelling to meet you next week for a holiday? The answer might change depending on this.

Comment: My situation is  the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The last sentence "My family is away for a week." sounds the best although I would say "My family is away for *the*/*this* week." instead since your situation refers to a specific week.

Comment: for a week? or for the week?

Comment: I would say "the" week.

Comment: @pro.mean No difference between the two, except that "the week" emphasizes that they're away this week (but saying they're away for "a week" is taken to mean the same thing, since you don't say "they _will_ be away for a week" and are therefore talking about the present). But I concur, the last option ("My family is away for a week") sounds most natural.